# appium giving TypeError: fn must be a function error

Tags: macos, selenium, appium

I am running appium on OSX machine. I have installed appium using below command `npm install -g appium` and I have also installed `npm install wd` but I am receiving below error on running `appium` from terminal.

```
TypeError: fn must be a function
    See 
    at Function.Promise.promisify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promisify.js:268:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (lib/fs.js:48:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/build/lib/tempdir.js:12:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/build/index.js:11:19)
```

Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgraded appium to 1.4.10 and error was removed.